# How to create a custom marker which load image Url with Background Clip shape in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-dependencies

I want to code a custom marker which can load a profile pic of a user which is from API and the background should bind with the clip shape which is customized....

[click here for view design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPq9R.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use the google maps package, the marker in the package takes BitmapDescriptor, so basically you can load an image from asset. I did not try to add a margin to the marker icon, in my case I just edited the image.

```
final Uint8List markerIcon = await getBytesFromAsset('assets/images/map_pin.png', 600);
BitmapDescriptor customIcon = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerIcon);
marker.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(currentLocation!.latitude.toString()),
        position: currentLocation!,
        draggable: true,
        icon: customIcon,
        onDragEnd: (LatLng latlng) {
          currentLocation = latlng;
        }));
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i need to load a image from api and i need a bind the border/ background design mainly...anyway thanks for the answers...

Comment: you can get the network image as a Uint8List. http.Response response = await http.Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://flutter.io/images/flutter-mark-square-100.png'),
); 
final Uint8List markerIcon = await response.bodyBytes

Comment: also you may find this answer helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56597739/how-to-customize-google-maps-marker-icon-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `ClipPath` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAUebVIb-7s and using some custom paths.

And then, position the map and your marker with a Stack widget.